# Convert Java Anonymous Interface Call to C#

Tags: java, c#, xamarin

I have been working the last few days on trying to integrate an Android Alien ALR-H450 Reader into our project. We currently are using C# and Xamarin in our project so I have to do some conversion from Java to C# from the documentation.

The problem I am having however is I have been unable to replicate the intended behavior from the device in Xamarin.

This is the block of code that I need to replicate in C#.

```
// Create BarcodeReader instance
BarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader(androidContext);

// Start barcode scan
barcodeReader.start(new BarcodeCallback() {
@Override
 public void onBarcodeRead(String barcode) {
     String detectedBarcode = barcode;
     // Scan will automatically stop after successfully scanning a barcode
    }
 });
```

And here is the interface being implemented

```
package com.alien.barcode;

public abstract interface BarcodeCallback
{
  public abstract void onBarcodeRead(String paramString);
}
```

I have implemented this as a separate class already, but I have no idea what is needed. I believe that maybe I need to make OnBarcodeRead an event in C# at this point I don't even know where to begin.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what interface barcodeReader provides. Can you provide what interface barcodeReader implements?

Comment: The binding project should generate an IBarcodeCallback interface in C#, so the class that you want to receive the OnBarcodeRead event should implement that interface.